# Where to initialize i, globally is not accepting

Tags: python, pyqt4

After each push of my button `def update` got executed and my initialising instruction for i (i=0) is not allowing to increment i. Where to initialize i, globally is not accepting.

Here is my Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class incre(QDialog):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(incre, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Button=QPushButton("Press")
        grid=QVBoxLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.Button)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.connect(self.Button,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.update)

    def update(self):
        i=0
        i=i+1
        print i


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    form=incre()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to initialize `i` in `__init__` method and make it attrubute of `incre` class. Then `i` will initialized only once when you create `incre` instance.

```
class incre(QDialog):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(incre, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Button=QPushButton("Press")
        grid=QVBoxLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.Button)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.connect(self.Button,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.update)
        self.i = 0

    def update(self):
        self.i += 1
        print self.i
```